# In Thunderbird, using the Stylish extension, how to target CSS rules at messages from specific domains?

Tags: email, thunderbird, rss, css

[Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/stylish/) is an extension for both Firefox and Thunderbird, which enables user CSS rules.  In Firefox, people use it just as commonly to tweak the UI as to change the look and feel of sites they frequent.  In Thunderbird, it seems like everyone is just using it to tweak the UI chrome, and ignoring other possible applications.

I want to use it to remove useless headers and footers from e-mail bulletins and RSS feeds.  This seems to work without a hitch, but I can't figure out how to target specific URLs or senders...  For Firefox, [one typically specifies rules in either of the follow two ways](http://userstyles.org/help/coding):

```
@-moz-document domain('images.example.com')
@-moz-document url-prefix('http://example.com/images')
```

This doesn't seem to work for me on e-mails and RSS feeds in Thunderbird...

```
@-moz-document domain('gumtree.pl')
.newHeader, .viewadhdr, .safety_message, .footer {display: none;}
```

-:  Any ideas?

Comment: I should add that, without the first @-moz-document line, the style works as intended.

Comment: My bad - I had an obvious syntax error...  d-:

It should look like this:

    @-moz-document domain('gumtree.pl')
      **{** .newHeader, .viewadhdr, .safety_message, .footer {display: none;} **}**

That works.  [-:  Can't answer my own question for another eight hours, 'cos I don't have a high enough rep.  d-: